# Dúvida sobre edittext (escrever e automaticamente inserir o ".")

Tags: android-studio

Boa noite amigos,

estou querendo saber como faço para eu ao inserir números em um edittext quando o usuário digitar e passar do número 00.000 vir esse "."

Ex:

edittext -  insira a quilometragem do seu carro
user -      90.000 km

obrigado!

Comment: dê uma olhada [aqui](http://jansenfelipe.com.br/2015/05/08/android-como-inserir-mascara-em-um-edittext/) é uma lib onde vc adiciona a dependência no Android studio e cria a máscara que vc deseja.